# Why does chrome fonts not show as nice as other browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, fonts

I'm running the latest versions of Chrome, IE and FF.  In terms of readability Chrome does not perform well in this area.  Any reasons why?

[image]

[High res version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18120120/Image%201.png)

As the font get's smaller (as in the comments section of the screenshot) it becomes increasing difficult to read compared to the other browsers.

Any easy fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have non-standard fonts in use. Here's what I see.

[image]

Check fonts specified in Chrome: Spanner, Options, Under Bonnet, Customise fonts, ...

The page you show has rather complicated HTML and CSS but I believe it is specifying 
`font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,default;` If this were the problem (e.g. if you had  Helvetica Neue installed where I don't) I would expect it to affect other browsers on the same PC.

I don't see the same issue with Chrome.

Comment: I do indeed have Helvetica Neue installed.  Seems strange that the website designers would choose such a bad font

Comment: It appears that your version of Helvetica Neue may not be optimized for Windows 7.